# Swift - How to update a variable from within different functions, when all the functions run on page load before the variable can be declared

Tags: swift, function, variables, viewdidload

Where would I declare the variable `total` when I want it to be updated from within the functions but when the functions must run on page loading.

Take a look at the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {                
     super.viewDidLoad()
            
     self.functionOne()
     self.functionTwo()
     self.printTotal()                
}
                            
var total = 0

func functionOne(){
      total += 1
}

func functionTwo(){        
    total += 1
}

func printTotal(){
    print(total)
}
```

Obviously I cannot declare the variable where it is at the moment, as the functions have already run by this point and the total would be set back to 0.

I also cannot move the variable declaration inside the function as that alters the scope and is no longer accessible to the other functions.

Furthermore I cannot declare the variable before the other functions run on page load because `viewDidLoad()` is a function in itself and therefore I could not access the variable from outside it.

The functions must run on page load as well, I cannot change that.

NB: I am not just trying to add two numbers together here, I know there are easier ways of doing that. This is just a grossly oversimplified example of the problem I am trying to overcome.

Comment: _"I cannot declare the variable where it is at the moment"_, yes you can and you should

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How come if I try and declare the variable where it is, I always returns 0 and not 2?

Comment: What exactly returns 0?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson If I print(total), it prints 0.

Comment: I just tested this and it prints 2, see [here](https://repl.it/@joadan/MiserlyLongObjectdatabase#main.swift)

Comment: Hmm okay I feel like this problem is more complicated than I first thought. Can you explain how that variable is still initialised even though its position in the code means it is set after the functions are called?

Comment: `total` is a property of your object, that's why (I guess, since you didn't show, but I guess you are in a UIViewController?). It's not following an order. Imagine your struct/object like having a pool of variable and a pool a functions, there aren't ordered.

Comment: To clarify my first comment, when I said you should I meant you should place it at the class level as a property and as Larme says the order is irrelevant.